# How to give a record that is being randomly selected from a database a link

Tags: php

I currently have a database with "Pokemon Cards" stored inside it, and I use the RAND function to generate 6 random cards in the style of a pack opening, however I want to be able to give these cards links, so you can click on a card that you open and it will take you to a page for that card.

My code to display the cards is as follows:

```
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Cards ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 6");
    //Output the results to the screen
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    ?><img src="<?php echo $row["Image"]; ?>"height="" width=""><?php;    
    }
```

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks Jamie.

Comment: It may be useful if you provide the Schema of Cards and any details regarding if/how you currently access/create the detail page for a card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it helps.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Cards ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 6");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<a href="path-to-the-page?card_id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $row["Image"]; ?>" height="" width="">
</a>
<?php }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have something unique in your pokemon table? a card name, or an id? if yes - use it to generate the link to the other page, which accepts this name either in [url path segments](http://doriantaylor.com/policy/http-url-path-parameter-syntax), [GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) parameters or [POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) parameters.
Then you need to write another script and grab the passed data, select the data from the database and output whatever you want there.

Comment: Yes I am trying to use the ID field which auto increments for each card I add to the database, I can link each card to the same form but after that I get lost, fairly new to PHP haha

Comment: the example given by @aakash-martand in http://stackoverflow.com/a/40110981/5992118 shows the part of generating the link, i've mentioned above.